# Применение Haskell для написания мобильных приложений, приложений для Windows web-приложений

Tags: haskell, мобильные-приложения, web-apps

Начинаю осваивать Haskell, но все уроки и руководства - работа в консоли. Подскажите, возможно ли, например, написать мобильное приложение на языке Haskell, и посоветуйте руководство именно по этой прикладной задаче, или Haskell - это просто вычислялка в консоли?

Answer (score 0):

Для Web существует много фреймворков, Yesod и Snap, наверное, самые крупные из них.

Касательно мобильных приложений, достаточно переформулировать вопрос как "Можно ли писать мобильные приложения на С?" Ответ, наверное, утвердительный, но вряд ли это удобно.

По поводу графических приложений для десктопа - см. пункт про мобильные приложения. На GTK можно делать окошки и под никсы, и под винду.

Comment: Но на C# вполне можно писать мобильные приложения, и я бы не сказал, что это неудобно. Касательно мобильных приложений я хотел спросить, какое существует применение Haskell, к примеру, существуют ли какие-то (отдельные) компиляторы, которые позволяют генерировать из файла *.hs, например файл *.apk, который затем можно распаковать на мобильном устройстве?